# PostgreSQL query to HTML table dynamically

Tags: html, json, postgresql, express

I was looking for an answer to this, it is fairly simple problem for experienced, but not for me,so pls understand newbie.
Object is very simple. Get query in JSON from database and put it in HTML table. Node,Express and PostgreSQL are used and everything is fine. I get JSON from query in browser and full table in console. Now, I got really stuck when it comes to represent data in HTML table. I was trying some methods from different sources, but no luck so far. Column names are fixed(table header), no need to get them, but I need to populate dynamically html table in browser. I am making some mistake and i cant figure where....
My index.js looks like this:

```
const express = require ("express");
const app = express ();
const port = 12345;
const pool = require ("./postgres");

app.use (express.json())

//Routes

app.get("/machines",async(rec,res)=> {
    try {
        const query = await pool.query ("SELECT br_ap,sticker,total_deposit*dn as \"Uplata\",total_withdraw*dn as \"Isplata\",\n" +
        "COALESCE(total_deposit,0)*dn - COALESCE(total_withdraw,0)*dn \n" +
        "as \"TOTAL\" ,lok FROM public.get_act_sab('03-04-2022 12:00', '05-05-2022 12:00')  \n" +
        "where lok='Lebane' order by br_ap");
        //res.json(query.rows);
        res.sendFile (__dirname + '/table.html');
        console.table(query.rows);
        console.log("Broj aparata je: "+query.rowCount)
        console.log(query.rows[0])
        console.log(query.rows[0].sticker)
        
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }
})

app.listen (port,() => {
    console.log("Server up and running on port " +port)
});
```

My HTML looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <table style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Broj aparata</th>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Sticker</th>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Uplata</th>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Isplata</th>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Total IN-OUT</th>
                <th style="padding: 20px;"> Lokacija </th>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
                <td style="padding: 20px;text-align:right;">1</td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        
    
        buildTable(query)

        function buildTable(data) {
            const table = document.getElementById ("myTable")
        
            for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
                var row = `<tr>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].br_ap}</td>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].sticker}</td>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].Uplata}</td>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].Isplata}</td>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].TOTAL}</td>
                                <td>${data.rows[i].lok}</td>
                            </tr>`
                table.innerHTML += row
            }
        } 
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Pls dont mind console output,hardcoded "ones" in a table and ugly query (it was pasted from Postgres), those are for testing.I get ones in table,nothing else.
I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but I dont know is it wrong function argument, or wrong approach whatsoever.
Any help would be appreciated. I just need to learn this,thank u for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Best if you create element on the fly with native javascript.

```js
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
 const td = document.createElement("td");
 tr.innerHTML = data.rows[i].br_ap
 table.appendChild(tr);

}
```

Comment: Ok, I get what it does but and am open for any method that will work, but can u tell me where to put this code ? HTML script ?

Comment: This a vanilla JavaScript code, which you will need to put in JavaScript file or, set a script tag inside the HTML

Comment: No...it doesnt work... I get no data in the table aside from those hardcoded "ones"... Must be something with injection of query result to html script...but I cant get it to work.